# HTML5 canvas save image to JPEG?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an HTML5 canvas:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I try to save its content to JPEG (and download it or open it in a new window)

I tried with:

```
var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
this.href = dt;
```

And I got an security error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

Is there a way to achieve that task WITHOUT using server side PHP scripts?

Comment: SECURITY_ERR exception raise when image drawn on canvas is not hosted on domain from where code is executing. below link might help you. http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

Answer (score 1):

Images that originate from a different server than the server that supplied the web page code will cause any html canvas that draws that image to become "tainted".  Tainted canvases may not export their image data...

Here's why:

Your browser has built-in safeguards to deter malicious software from stealing important information from you.  This includes stealing an image of your bank login screen which could be accomplished if html canvas was allowed to (1) create an image of your login screen using html canvas and (2) transmit that image to a thief using canvas.toDataURL.

The solution is simple (no scripts required).  Just put your images on the same server as your .html, .css and .js files and serve all files from that server.

Comment: When you have control over the server you load your images from, you can also prevent tainting by defining a [CORS directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on the source server. How to do this depends on what webserver software you are using.